# Create a VSCode style menu in electron

Tags: javascript, user-interface, electron

I am exploring electron for the past week and I come across a question about how can I create a costume menu in Electron just like VSCode does have it. Just like this:

**My Menu:** This is how by default Electron creates the menu in your application; However, how can I move my menu to the blue bar, just like it is shown in the picture.

[image]

**VSCode Menu:** This is how I want to create my menu, just like VSCode has it. I was thinking of doing it manually (using ul, li on HTML), however, I wonder if there could be a way to use the menu created by electron and exporter it into HTML, or if there is any other better way to do a costume menu just like VSCode have.

[image]

Comment: https://alextorressk.com/custom-electron-titlebar/

Comment: WOW, That is precisely what I was looking for. What you very much!

Comment: Here is an updated link for the answer: https://github.com/AlexTorresDev/custom-electron-titlebar

Answer (score 1):

I've recently started playing with electron. And I was also concerned about Menus. What I found is that you can either use the Menu from Electron or you can create your own stylish navbar and set application menu to `null`. This is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

I found this new link about a package that will help with my question:
https://github.com/AlexTorresDev/custom-electron-titlebar